# Solving second order ODE by using convolution integral and Laplace transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

$$y''+3y'+2y=\cos(at) $$

where a is a constant. Find solution of this initial value problem in terms of convolution integral.$( y(0)=1$ and $ y'(0)=0 )$

I couldn't solve this problem with convolution integral. If somebody helps me, I'll appreciate.

I found:
$$Y(s)=\dfrac 1 {s^2+3s+2} \left(\dfrac s {s^2+a^2}+s+3 \right)$$ with Laplace transformation.After this, I have to use convolution integral. When I use it, the integral becomes too difficult. Actually, I found the result of the integral but I think the result is wrong.

Comment: I hope I didn't change your math

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is so helpful.

Comment: yx Mahmut .....

Answer (score 1):

Use fraction decomposition
$$Y(s)=\dfrac 1 {s^2+3s+2} \left(\dfrac s {s^2+a^2}+s+3 \right)$$
Note that we have:
$$s^2+3s+2=(s+2)(s+1)$$
And
$$f(s)=\dfrac {s+3} {(s+2)(s+1)}=\dfrac {2} {(s+1)}-\dfrac {1} {(s+2)}$$
Find the inverse Laplace transform of $f(s)$
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}} \{f(s)\}=2e^{-t}-e^{-2t}$$
On the other part
$$g(s)=\dfrac s {(s^2+a^2)(s+2)(s+1)}$$
$$g(s)=\dfrac 2 {(s^2+a^2)(s+2)}-\dfrac 1 {(s^2+a^2)(s+1)}$$
Here you have to use the convolution integral formula.For the left fraction you can write:
$$h(s)=\dfrac 2 {(s^2+a^2)(s+2)}=\mathcal {L} \left (\dfrac 1a \sin(at)\right ) \mathcal{L}\left (2e^{-2t} \right)$$
$$ \implies h(t)=\frac 2 a\int_0^t \sin(a\tau)e^{-2(t-\tau)}d\tau$$
So that 
$$g(t)=\frac 2 a\int_0^t \sin(a\tau)e^{-2(t-\tau)}d\tau-\frac 1a\int_0^t \sin(a\tau)e^{-(t-\tau)}d\tau$$
$$g(t)= \dfrac {2e^{-2t}} a\int_0^t \sin(a\tau)e^{2\tau}d\tau- \dfrac {e^{-t}}a\int_0^t \sin(a\tau)e^{\tau}d\tau$$
Evaluate both integrals.

Then you can deduce $y(t)$ since:
$$y(t)=g(t)+f(t)$$
$$y(t)=g(t)+2e^{-t}-e^{-2t}$$

Comment: You found g(t) and f(t). But I have trouble with finding y(t). You said Y(s)=f(s)*g(s). You found y(s) and g(s). To find y(t), we need to use convolution again. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mahmutalidurukan I added some lines at the end. You only need to evalute the two integrals and deduce the answer. Mahmut

Comment: I thought y(t)=f(t)*g(t). That's my mistake. Huge favor. Thanks again

Comment: No @mahmutalidurukan it's a sum of functions not a product of functions. So you just need to add both functions to  get $y(t)$. Yo're welcome Mahmut